# How to fix the username and password for WebMatrix and SQL Server Compact?

Tags: php, sql-server, webmatrix

I'm using WebMatrix3.
I created a SQL server compact database.

The username is probably root but I do not know the password.

WebMatrix doesn't appear to have a place where you can set those.
How can I set the username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the password should just be left blank just input the username and log in.